# Contours / Connected components in OpenCV 2.4.4

Tags: c++, opencv, stdvector, contour, mat

I'm currently working on an image with a lot of detected contours.
My goal is to narrow down the number of contours to end up with only the one I'm looking for.
For that I conduct a bunch of tests based on area and bounding box.

For now I do after every step a `drawContours` for the contours that I want to keep followed by a `findContours`.

**My problem is** that I would like to do `findContours` only once and then just erase the contours I don't want, is this possible?

Current way :

```
Mat src;
Mat BW;
src = imread("img.bmp", 0);
if( src.channels() > 1)
{
  cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);
}

threshold(src, BW, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
imshow( "Tresh", BW );

Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
Mat dstP = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
Mat dst1 = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
Mat dst2 = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( BW, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    Scalar color( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
    drawContours( dst, contours, i, color, 2/*CV_FILLED*/, 8, hierarchy );
}

/// Test on area  ******************************************************************
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( contourArea(contours[i], false) > 100 && contourArea(contours[i], false) < 200000)
    {
        Scalar color( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
        drawContours( dst1, contours, i, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
    }
}

/// Next test **********************************************************************
    cvtColor(dst1, dstP, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    findContours( dstP, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

etc

Wanted way :

```
if ( contourArea(contours[i], false) < 100 && contourArea(contours[i], false) > 200000)
{
    contours.erase(i); // Doesn't work
}
```

Does anyone now how to erase those contours?

PS : I don't care about inner contours, I want all of them to go trough my tests.

---

**EDIT**, the solution (pointed out by limonana) is : `contours.erase(contours.begin()+i);`

Comment: May be you can create a new countour structure and keep adding those which pass your test.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Where is the rest of the data being kept?